# Как в discord отправить ссылку от имени бота, но без вложения?

Tags: python, бот, discord

Когда бот отправляет какую либо ссылку в текстовый канал. Дискорд автоматически создает вложение от сайта, которое, при большом количестве ссылок, занимает много места. Как можно отправить ссылку без этого вложения?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как сделать так, чтобы в сообщении осталась только ссылка?**

Код:

```
@bot.command()
async def random_url(ctx, arg):
    author = ctx.message.author

    if (arg == '1'):
        await ctx.send(f'{author.mention}, создаю ссылку...')
        url = URL_Generator()
        await author.send(url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Спустя 1,5 месяца решение найдено :)**

Нужно всего лишь, при отправке, заключить ссылку в `<>`, то есть вот так:

```
await author.send(f'<{url}>')
```